# Quasar invokeAny

Tags: java, multithreading, quasar

I wrote an ExecutorService that is used to execute a number of Threads in parallel and get the first result found, I use the "invokeAny" method to accomplish that.

Something similar to the following:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;


public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
        Set<Callable<String>> callables = new HashSet<Callable<String>>();

        callables.add(new Callable<String>() {
            public String call() throws Exception {
                System.out.println("Task 1 started...");
                return "Task 1 Finished";
            }
        });


        callables.add(new Callable<String>() {
            public String call() throws Exception {
                System.out.println("Task2 started...");
                return "Task 2 Finished";
            }
        });

        callables.add(new Callable<String>() {
            public String call() throws Exception {
                return "Task 3 Finished";
            }
        });

        try {
            String result = executorService.invokeAny(callables);
            System.out.println("result = " + result);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        executorService.shutdown();
    }

}
```

Everything works fine but because my code executes a lot of Threads, there is a huge amount of resources (CPU) used. So I had a look on internet and I found that people suggest to use Quasar, for those kind of problems...
Basing on the specification it should work as the java "concurrent" framework, so I had a look and I found the class "***FiberExecutorScheduler***", that seems promising, but I cannot find a way to organize my work in order to realize the same behaviour of my previous code.

Is there a way to implement that with Quasar?
Can you please provide an example?
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As per fiber docs, you can translate your Callable to a Fiber as per the code below, where V is your return type.

```
new Fiber<V>() {
  @Override
  protected V run() throws SuspendExecution, InterruptedException {
        // your code
    }
}.start();
```

And you can translate your `ExecutorService` to a `FiberExecutorScheduler`, where you can call `newFiber` to add your fiber to the executor.

I found the documentation for this library very lacking. No usage examples, even on their own website. Looking into their repo, I found the following test case.

```
@Test
public void simpleTest1() throws Exception {
    final CompletableFuture<String> fut = new CompletableFuture<String>();

    final Fiber<String> fiber = new Fiber<>(scheduler, () -> {
        try {
            return AsyncCompletionStage.get(fut);
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }).start();

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
                fut.complete("hi!");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }).start();

    assertThat(fiber.get(), equalTo("hi!"));

}
```

I would try to go on based on this test case if I were you.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, but I didn't get it, method newFiber of FiberExecutorScheduler takes "SuspendableCallable" object and not a Fiber... So I cannot pass it to it. And how the first part of your answer is linked to the second? In the first part you suggest to use the FiberExecutorScheduler, but in the "simpleTest1" is not used at all... I'm a little bit confused...